# Reformulate Einstein equations to make them linear

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, non-linear-systems

Is it possible to reformulate the Einstein equation in terms of a new variable, say $k_{\mu\nu}$ in terms of the metric  $g_{\mu\nu}$, in order to make the Einstein equations linear in $k_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: I do not understand the question? What do you mean with linear in $k$?   Do you want to rewrite the Einstein equation as just a linear function of only the metric components?

Comment: Whether it is possible to find a non-linear transformation that the Einstein equation in this new variable $k_{\mu\nu}$ not not contain any terms that are higher-order in  $k_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Technically the Einstein equations are linear in the Einsten tensor $G_{\mu\nu}$....

Answer (score 5):

It is of course possible to linearize Einstein's field equations (EFEs).
Usually one approximates the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ by the Minkowski part $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ and a small perturbation often called $h_{\mu\nu}$ (Of course it can also be called $k_{\mu\nu}$):

$$g_{\mu\nu}\approx \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$$

Then after omitting terms of second order and making use of some freedom in the choice of coordinate system (in this particular case it can also be considered as some gauge transformation freedom of the $h_{\mu\nu}$)
one can find the linearized form of the EFEs

$$\Box h_{\mu\nu} = \kappa (T_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}\eta_{\mu\nu}T)$$

where $\kappa = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4}$, $T_{\mu\nu}$ is the energy momentum tensor and $T =T^\mu_\mu$ is its trace. The derivation can be found in the usual text books (Landau & Lifshitz Classical Field Theory or Wheeler & Thorne & Misner Gravitation etc.).

Comment: Thanks. However, I was wondering if there exists some reformulation, in which the linearity is exact.

Comment: Just to add to the notational confusion, $h_{\mu\nu}$ is sometimes given a coefficient, denoted $\kappa$ but not meaning $8\pi G/c^4$, such that calculations can be expanded in powers of such a $\kappa$ to understand the effects of a weak field.

Comment: It's not, in general, possible to turn a non-linear equation into a linear one: they have different physical properties. You can find special cases that are linear, or a linear approximation, but you can't make the Einstein Field Equations linear any more than you could make $y = e^x$ linear.

Comment: @EricSmith Sure, for instance Mercury perihel precision cannot be explained with the linear theory. The nonlinearities have gone away.

Comment: @konstle Searching for such a transformation amounts more or less for the search of the perpetuum mobile. Making a nonlinear equation linear always neglects some part of the physics behind the nonlinear equation.

Comment: @EricSmith   $y= e^x$ is in fact linear in $e^x$, and so is an example where thd OP's agenda succeeds, not where it fails.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to reformulate the Einstein equation … to make <*them*> linear …

Generally, no. However, there are many situations where exact solutions to (fully nonlinear) Einstein equations can be obtained from solutions of the linear equations. Here are a few examples:

- For metrics admitting *Kerr–Schild form*,
  $$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+l_\mu l_\nu,$$ where $\eta$ is a Minkowski metric and $l$ is a null vector field, the “perturbation” $l_\mu l_\nu $ solves both linearized and full Einstein equations. Among the solutions admitting this  form are Schwartzschild and Kerr metrics.
- Metric of static axially-symmetric spacetime can be written in *Weyl canonical form*:
  $$ds^2 = −e^{2U } dt^2 + e^{−2U}\left [e^{2γ}(dρ^2 + dz^2) + ρ^2dφ^2 \right] ,$$
  where functions $U$ and $γ$ depend on $ρ$ and $z$. The vacuum EFEs for function $U$ reduce to *linear* equation:
  $$ U_{,ρρ}+ \frac 1 ρ U_{,ρ}+ U_{,zz} = 0 , $$ that coincides with a Laplace equation in an “unphysical” flat space with cylindrical coordinates $ρ$, $z$, $φ$. The remaining function $γ$ can be expressed as quadrature once $U$ is known. Note, that while it is easy to write a solution to Laplace equation, there are a lot of subtleties in interpreting corresponding spacetime, and in finding  solutions of physical importance.
- For spacetimes admitting *two commuting Killing vectors* in 1978 Belinski & Zakharov demonstrated *complete integrability* of symmetry reduced Einstein equations by constructing overdetermined linear system with a free “spectral parameter” and showing the equivalence of integrability conditions for that system to (reduced) Einstein equations. This result led to many solution generating methods a lot of which require solving linear equations only. Note, that *complete integrability* for a system of nonlinear PDEs does not necessarily mean that all its solutions can be written explicitly, but rather this means that there exist rich structures, such as infinite number of conservation laws, infinitely-dimensional symmetries etc.